# Mapping existing Image with new content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-nodes, drupal-files

I am facing a situation here.

I have a content type A with an image field(field_upload_snaps) in it. There is another content type B which also contains an image field(field_valid_snaps).

Now user will upload the pics from A content type. So if user upload 3 pics via A then 3 FID and their corresponding URIs will be created in file_managed table in Drupal 7.

Now I have a requirement where I have to insert 2 images out of 3 programatically using Drupal code. Now there is no need to generate any new image copy in public URI as images already exist via A.

I tried two approaches:-

1) I have created a new node of Type B. I tried to fetch file URI,filesize,filemime and all relevant parameter from existing fid and associate with the node using this.

```
global $user;
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = "user_slideshow_snaps";
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$file = (object) array(
 'uid' => $user->uid,
 'uri' => 'public://1.jpeg" ,
 'filemime' => 'image/jpeg',
 'status' => 1,
 ); 

$node->field_upload_snaps['und'][] = (array)$file;
$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
node_save($node);
```

But it gives me an error that "Cant insert duplicate value in file_managed". It will give because such value already exist in file_managed via A. So I am not able to save value.

2) I saved node first and then manually insert in the image field like this.

```
global $user;
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = "user_slideshow_snaps";
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
node_save($node);

db_insert('field_data_field_valid_snaps')
->fields(array(     
'entity_type' => 'node',
'bundle' => 'user_actualD_snaps',
'deleted'=> 0,
'entity_id'=>$node->nid,
'delta'=>0,
'field_valid_snaps_fid'=>517,
'field_valid_snaps_alt'=>'',
'field_valid_snaps_title'=>'',
'field_valid_snaps_width'=>200,
'field_valid_snaps_height'=>300, 
))
->execute();
```

But the line after node_save() doesnt execute in this case. So I am not able to save it.

Are there any functions available which will map existing images into another table?

Answer (score 2):

YOUR SOLUTION!!
$url = "YOUR FILE URL";

//$node = new StdClass();

or

//$node = node_load("YOUR NODE ID");

```
$file_data = file_get_contents($url);
if ($file_data) {
    $directory = file_default_scheme() . '://public';
    $path = file_stream_wrapper_uri_normalize($directory . 'GIVE YOUR FILE NAME');
    $file = file_save_data($file_data, $path, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    if ($file->fid > 0) {
    // REPLACE WITH YOUR FIELD NAME
        $node->field_XXXX = array(
          'und' => array(
            0 => array(
              'fid' => $file->fid,
              'uri' => $file,
              'display' => '1',
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
    node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: file_save_data will save the same file once again with different name. I have already the original file kept there so I dont need to create a replica of same file with different name. I want to use the properties of existing saved file to load a new node. I hope I am clear with my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

File_load API solved my problem of getting the dimensions of existing file and save in another content type.